# How to play 2 youtube videos at the same time with Youtube player API?

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to create an Android application that, once searched for a video on youtube, plays it simultaneously in two `YoutubePlayerViews`, that is the code of the `PlayerActivity`

```
public abstract class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayerView playerView, playerView1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        playerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        playerView1 = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player_view1);
        playerView.initialize(YoutubeConnector.KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
                                                YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                                boolean restored) {
                if (!restored) {
                    player.cueVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
                }
            }
        });
        playerView1.initialize(YoutubeConnector.KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
                                                YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                                boolean restored) {
                if (!restored) {
                    player.cueVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
                }
            }
        });
        TextView video_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player_title);
        TextView video_desc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player_description);
        TextView video_id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.player_id);
        video_title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_TITLE"));
        video_id.setText("Video ID : "+(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID")));
        video_desc.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_DESC"));
    }
}
```

the problem is that one video loads while the other remains on a black screen, this API allows simultaneously riproduction?